# Вопрос по получению данных с сервера используя axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

Пока использую `commit('setTasks', alltask.data);` получаю все данные в таком ввиде:

```
{ "userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "delectus aut autem", "completed": false }
{ "userId": 1, "id": 2, "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui", "completed": false }
{ "userId": 1, "id": 3, "title": "fugiat veniam minus", "completed": false }
{ "userId": 1, "id": 4, "title": "et porro tempora", "completed": true }
{ "userId": 1, "id": 5, "title": "laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum", "completed": false }
```

Но, мне нужно получать только `title` соответственно пишу `commit('setTasks', alltask.data.title)` но, тогда вообще ничего не отображается. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю( Как получить только `title` в свой массив

```
  actions: {
    getAllTasks({ commit }) {
      return axios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', {
        method: 'GET',
      })
        .then((alltask) => {
          commit('setTasks', alltask.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
  },
```

Comment: alltask.data - это массив? Тогда alltask.data.map(task => task.title)

Comment: Большое спасибо) Помогли!)

Answer (score 0):

Всего-то надо было замапить и вернуть масивку с даными только с полей title)))

```
 actions: {
        getAllTasks({ commit }) {
          return axios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', {
            method: 'GET',
          })
            .then((alltask) => {
              commit('setTasks', alltask.data.map(task => task.title);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
            });
        },
      },
```